# Require Description to Hyperlink column entry in SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I'm working on a custom New/Edit Form for a SharePoint list with JavaScript.  I am hiding fields that I don't want the user to see, and requiring other fields. I have not had trouble hiding the fields I don't want the users to see. Yet, I am requiring the URL/Hyperlink input, and having a problem with the input.  Yes, the address field is required, as I want, but also, I need the user to enter information in the Description field for the hyperlink address.  Is it possible to force this secondary field in the column entry to be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!  I finally got a solution.  It was a little tricky to do, and find information for, but I think I got it.  I had to go about detecting if the URLFieldDescription was blank or not.  I did this by adding $.fn.extend code to the JSLink file, like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    vals: function () {
        var retVals = []; 

        this.each(function () {
            retVals.push($(this).val())
        }); 

        return retVals; 
    }
});

var formInputs = "[id*='URLFieldDescription']";

$(formInputs).bind('keyup keydown change', function () {
    var entries = $(formInputs).vals();

    for (i in entries) {
        if (entries[i] == '') {
            $("input[name$='diidIOSaveItem']").prop('disabled',true);
            return;
        }
    }

    $("input[name$='diidIOSaveItem']").prop('disabled',false);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think you can add the HTML5 `required`-property to the Description-field followingly:

```
$("input").prop('required',true);
```

Comment: I believe that would work fine with the standard HTML5 input declaration.  Yet, this is done from SharePoint with an ASPX file.  I have found some potential information regarding it, http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-3.html . But nothing pertaining to a Hyperlink list item.   They are a little different.  Thanks though.

Comment: Nothing stops you from inserting a Content Editor Web Part with a JS-file including this jQuery to the `EditForm.aspx` of your list.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  How should I alter the actions of the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx with the CEWP?  I've only currently been using the JS Link Miscellaneous option with the list forms, New and Edit.

Comment: You can add the CEWP to your `EditForm.aspx` and to `NewForm.aspx` by going to *cogwheel* > *Edit page* and inserting the wp while on either of the pages. Then edit the wp and input the link to your file containing the above jQuery to the *Content Link* -field. This needs to be done for both of your pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help Moe.  I looked at the source for the page, and did not see any <input> that addressed the Description field.  I have found a little more JavaScript options for the SP.FieldUrlValue object.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245305.aspx though, I haven't found a way to require it there either.  I'll keep looking to see if I can find an input definition specific to that field for SharePoint URL gathering, to require it.

Comment: Note: JSLink is the SP2013 way of linking a script file, CEWP is the (old) SharePoint way of linking a Scriptfile. They both do the same. Benefit of a CEWP after! the ListForm webpart is that you know all Form HTML is in the DOM, with JSLink you have to add code to wait for the DOM to be ready (eg. jQuery ready function) JSLink can also be used to load jQuery because it accepts any https address (in SharePoint online)

Comment: @moe Well, I tried the $('input').prop(required', true); option, and I think it worked in that it required the description <input> to be filled  in, but as well, it required all the inputs on the form to be filled in, as I suspected, as the 'input' is too general.  Is there a way I could distinguish the actual input element for just the URL description input?

Comment: As well, I had to go to the edit form for the list to unrequired the other fields I didn't need input on, by first requiring the field, as the fields properties from the list settings screen stated that the field(s) weren't required, and then unrequiring it, to get it back to a working format.  FYI

Comment: @MatthewDewell you can define the element you are after with basic JavaScript too. E.g. `document.getElementById("yourInputField").required = true;`. Just check the elements of the page with browser's inspection tool.

Comment: @moe Thanks for your further input.  I have one little problem.  It seems that SharePoint creates "random" identifier strings to identify each input field.  I think I may be onto something with this:

$('[id*="URLFieldDescription"]').prop('required', true);

I was looking at the F12 Developer Tools with IE11, and it was showing the text 'required=""' in the input field for the URLFieldDescription inputs.  Yet SharePoint still seems to take it even when it's empty and fill it in with the URL if it's blank.